# How do I determine which HostHeader the client used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I'm attempting to set some session variables depending on which hostHeader was used to access my site. Do I have to parse it out of the URI property or is there a better way? (MVC3/IIS7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [HttpWebRequest.Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host.aspx) property, which should be equivalent to accessing `Request.Headers["Host"]` in MVC.

It mentions it's used to "Get or set the Host header value to use in an HTTP request independent from the request URI." If you're not setting this somehow then "then the Host header value to use in an HTTP request is based on the request URI." So inspecting it via the `Request.Url.Host` or equivalent property is equally sufficient. I don't know of any other way.